# twitter-text on Android - how to link

Tags: android, twitter-bootstrap, twitter, hashtag, mention

I'm working on a twitter app reader for Android. The app itself is done but still bot contain the hashtag and mention detection.

I have found the twitter-text lib but I'm lost on How to show the hashtag/mentions. Url are working fine.

Currently I'm doing :

```
String tweet = mStatus.get(position).getText().toString();
Extractor MyExtractor = new Extractor();
List<Extractor.Entity> entityList = MyExtractor.extractEntitiesWithIndices(tweet);

Autolink MyAutoLink = new Autolink();
String str_analyse = MyAutoLink.autoLinkEntities(tweet,entityList);

//String str_analyse = MyAutoLink.autoLink(tweet);

viewHolder.status.setText(Html.fromHtml(str_analyse));
```

I saw that the str_analyse contain the

I was thinking that the use of autoLinkEntities, as it put the tag can help me.

Any idea ?

Seb

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest ways I think to go about doing this would be to use the SpannableString class (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html).

The following is a commented example of a Spannable String...

Create the textview and desired message...

```
TextView textView = new TextView(this);
String twitterMessage = "Hello (seb)";
```

Find the first and last index of the clickable section...

```
int SpanStart = twitterMessage.indexOf("(");
int SpanEnd = twitterMessage.indexOf(")");
```

Change the textview and create your Spannable...

```
textView.setText(twitterMessage, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
Spannable spannable = (Spannable)textView.getText();
```

Create your ClickableSpan with OnClick methods...

```
ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan()
{
@Override
public void onClick(View widget) { 
Intent userProfile = new Intent(getApplicatonContext(),UserProfile.class);
startActivity(userProfile)
}
};
```

Set your Spannable to use that ClickableSpan using .setSpan()...

```
spannable.setSpan(clickableSpan, SpanStart, SpanEnd +1,Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

I would advise you to do more research into this class to make sure it is the write method for your app. Hope this helps :)